# How can I convert a data that comes in the form of a model into a unique still?

Tags: arrays, swift

```swift
final class Person: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return ObjectIdentifier(self).hashValue
    }
    
    let id: Int
    let fullName: String
    
    init(id: Int, fullName: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.fullName = fullName
    }
}
```

In this model, data comes to me, what I want is to extract the repetitive ones, I tried a few ways but I couldn't get exactly the result I wanted.

```swift
defer {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.view?.tableViewReload()
        self.view?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
if let people = response?.people {
    defer {
        let uniq = Set(self.fethetuni)
        let arrayUniq = Array(uniq)
        self.fetchedPeopleUniq = arrayUniq
      
    }
    self.view?.emptyDataMessage(isEmpty: false)
    self.paginationManager.fetchedData(count: response?.people.count ?? 0)
    
    fethetuni.append(contentsOf: people)
}
```

This is one of the ways I tried, but it didn't work the way I wanted it to.

I need this newly created data as a [String] array. Id and fullname will be combined and then I need to get the `uniq` array

Comment: Conform to Hashable but let the compiler synthesise the code for you. Then using Set will work directly.